# Wordpress page url conflict with Subdirectory with same name

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, subdirectory

I am having wordrpress website https://feed.bluecue.co/ . I have created the page twitter feed with custom template to integrate twitter feed from php codes downloaded from github. the php plugin used for twitter feeds is dynamically creating an url https://feed.bluecue.co/twitter-feed/template.html. when i create this directory in cpanel then my page not working anymore.Taking me to directory instead of showing page. i cant find the script where this url is coming from. Url is created dynamically using some script. if i find this script where i can use an static url. then my problem is solved.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your website is working as expected. WordPress is handling the re-writing of your websites URL's. I'm not sure why you are trying to load a HTML file within your WordPress website. It would be very helpful to see what code you are using for the Twitter feed and how you are trying to use it on your WordPress website. -- It looks like you're possibly trying to run before you can walk...?

Comment: there is set of codes downloaded from Git called twitter feed. here is link http://twitterfeednew.bluecue.co. it creates dynamic url a for a template . i want this url http://feed.bluecue.co/twitter-feed/template.html to be considered as directory and  this url as http://feed.bluecue.co/twitter-feed/ wordpress page. But when i do this by creating directory in cpanel then page do not work . Please help

Answer (score 0):

can you try saving permalinks again
Hope this works for you

Comment: You didn't understand. please check console of the website http://feed.bluecue.co/twitter-feed/. you will find a 404 error. I want that issue to be solved